# Help with getting started on my own jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Im making my own little timepicker, calling it xxxtimepicker. Ill paste some code belowe, but the problem is that nothing happens. Any tips/tricks and help when making a addon that works like datepicker?

```
    (function($){

    var popupname = "timepickerpopup";

    function OpenWindow(parentObj) {

        var popup = $('<div id="'+popupname+'" style="">POPUP</div>');
        var offset = $(parentObj).offset();
        offset.top += 20;

        $(popup).offset( offset );

        $("body").append(popup);
        $("body").append('<script>$("#timepickerpopup").dialog({autoOpen: false});</script>');
    }

    function CloseWindow() {
        $("#"+popupname).remove();
    }

    $.fn.extend({

        xxxtimepicker: function() {

            var defaults = {
                varname: "val",
                var2name: "val"
            };

            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function() {

                var o = options;
                var obj = $(this);

                obj.bind("focus", OpenWindow(this));
                obj.bind("blur", CloseWindow);

            });
        }

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put functions OpenWindow() & CloseWindow() inside xxxtimepicker function. 
Tip: don't use global variables like `popupname` it creates problems for multiple xxxtimepicker on one page.